# Match with the last occurrence of same key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following input:

```
test = [{1:"i am Mike"},{3:"i am 20 years old"},{1:"i live in greece"},{7:"i love pizza"},{9:"i love basketball"}]
```

I want to find the first and the last occurrence of each key and then i want to group all the information between the first and the last occurrence and more specifically the string.
I want the following output:

```
test = [{1:"i am Mike i am 20 years old i live in greece"},{7:"i love pizza"},{9:"i love basketball"}]
```

Comment: What if there are multiple keys that occurs multiple times? I.e., what if the input is like `[{1:...}, {3:...}, {1:...}, {3:...}]`?

Comment: I think in your contrived example you meant to have `{1: "i am 20 years old"}`

Comment: No, i want anything between 1 .. in my problem if anything is between for example here we have number 3 it means that i will not have again 3...so i want to group from same number to same number

Comment: Where's your code, and what exactly is the problem with it? Give a [mre].

Comment: if i have a number that occurs more than one time i want everything that is between this number. the thing that you said  between the first pair of {1:...}, ..., {1:...} and then the last {1:...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First associate the ending index to each key in a separate dictionary.  Then combine these into non-overlapping ranges identifying the first key of each range.  Finally extract the strings from the dictionaries in each range:

```
ends   = { k:i for i,d in enumerate(test,1) for k in d }
ranges = [(0,)]
ranges.extend( (k,start,ends[k]) for start,d in enumerate(test) 
                for k in d if start==ranges[-1][-1] )
merged = [ {g:" ".join(d[k] for d in test[s:e] for k in d)} 
           for g,s,e in ranges[1:] ]
```

output:

```
print(merged)
[{1: 'i am Mike i am 20 years old i live in greece'}, 
 {7: 'i love pizza'}, 
 {9: 'i love basketball'}]
```

Comment: It works without problem!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

The no libraries or anything fancy aproach:

```
test = [{1: "i am Mike"}, {3: "i am 20 years old"}, {1: "i live in greece"}, {7: "i love pizza"},
    {9: "i love basketball"}]

tracking = [] 
output_str = []
result = []
for d in test:
    key, value = tuple(d.items())[0]
    output_str.append(value)
    if key in tracking:
        start = tracking.index(key)
        result += [{k: v} for (k, v) in zip(tracking[:start], output_str[:start])]
        tracking = tracking[start:]
        output_str = output_str[start:]
        result.append({key: ''.join(output_str)})
        tracking.clear()
        output_str.clear()
    else:
        tracking.append(key)

result += [{k: v} for (k, v) in zip(tracking, output_str)]
print(result)
```

This doesnt support 1 2 2 4 1 it will only merge 2 2

Comment: it is very close but i tried this `[{1: "i am Mike"}, {2: "i am 20 years old"}, {2: "i live in greece"}, {7: "i love pizza"},{9: "i love basketball"}]` and i dont see the number 1

Comment: Fixed  it!  some characters... .